# Apache Cordova File Plugin - Location

Tags: json, file, cordova, plugins

I am new to apache cordova and i'm testing some basilar things. I have to read some json from a text file, i see there ia a file plugin and a file transfer plugin. My question is: Where should i put this file to read it correctly? Is this possible ? If not, are there other methods to read some data on each different platform from a file? Thank you all.

Comment: you can put your json file in www folder.

Comment: i create a test.txt file in www folder, but this line of code gives me an error : fileSystem.root.getFile("www/test.txt", {create:false}, gotFileEntry, fail); am i missing something?

Comment: Also read this documentation https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/02/29/phonegap-storing-and-retrieving-with-the-filesystem/

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("www/test.txt", {create:false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
```

to be this:

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("test.txt", {create: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
```

And try by using alert in the below function,

```
function readAsText(file) {
        alert("readAstext");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {


               console.log("Read as text");
                console.log(evt.target.result);
                alert("content : "+evt.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
}
```